# Putting data in doc template using poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to insert data in some doc template and return it's changed value. I decided to use [POI](http://poi.apache.org/hwpf/), but if there are other ways to solve my problems I may change the library. I can change the string using [Range.replaceText()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/usermodel/Range.html), but by this way I loose my text formatting, and the text itself turns into plain document with no styles and tables. Are there any ways to replace some characters saving the formatting? I tried RTFTemplate, but it could slightly help me, because it depends on Spring, but I use vaadin in my project.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try with POI 3.8 beta 4? There has been a lot of work done on word editing very recently

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No, I didn't, thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

Several years ago I was solving similar problem. The easiest way was to use RTF files as templates, and avoid  using any parsing library, because MS Office RTF is not so standatd as you could expect, and any library that tries to "understand" this format tends to loose part of formatting.

So I just opened rtf files as plain text, and searched for my keywords within it. There was a problem when this keywords were splitted into several parts, divided by some non meaningful parts.

I will search my delphi sources and will try to port it to java later this week.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think your solution may be suit. But if a have to fill the table with content of some different entities of one POJO, can I just copy the entire row, to add a row to a table?

Comment: I Didn't try that, so just don't know.

Comment: How can I contact you outside this resource, to send you the sources? I have no time to port them, but I think that you, if you're interested can do that.